# zend framework simple action problem

Tags: zend-framework-mvc

i am creating a hello world project in Zend MVC with Zend Server. some how the routeing is wrong. I create the project by zend_tool zf.sh create project,  so it creates all directory itself, and i modified to indexController to try some actions like below, and all other file reminds the same..

```
<?php

class IndexController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{

    public function init()
    {
        /* Initialize action controller here */
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    }

    public function indexAction()
    {
        // action body
    $this->getResponse()->appendBody('hello from about Action');
    }

    public function aboutAction()
    {
    $this->getResponse()->appendBody('hello from about Action');
        // action body
    }


}
```

when i enter "http://localhost/index.php", it shows the correct info from indexAction();

when i enter "http://localhost/index", it shows page not found

**when i enter "http://localhost/index.php/about",** 
 it shows " Message: Invalid controller specified (about) "
Request Parameters:

array (
  **'controller' => 'about',**
  **'action' => 'index',**
  'module' => 'default',
)

i expect controller be index and action be about.. how can i fix it...

i have this in my apache config. i think i may have this configured wrong, but i dont know where.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
#DocumentRoot "/usr/local/zend/apache2/htdocs"
DocumentRoot /home/testuser/projects/helloworldproject/public
<Directory "/home/testuser/projects/helloworldproject/public/">
    SetEnv APPLICATION_ENV "development"
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from All
</Directory>
```

thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

- `localhost/index.php` should go to the `index` controller and the `index` action by default `(index, index)`.
- `localhost/index` should ALSO go to `(index,index)`
- `index.php/about` I would expect goes to `(about,index)`, that is the `about` controller and `index` action, but I could be wrong (I didn't test this).
- If you want to go to `(index,about)` you would go to `localhost/index/about`

You appear to have correctly defined the about action `public function aboutAction`, so that should work properly.
If you want to be able to go to localhost/about or localhost/about/index you will need to define an about controller like `class AboutController extends Zend_Controller_Action` as you've done for the `IndexController`.

**-- EDIT --**
Also, make sure your .htaccess looks at minimum like this:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: as i metioned. localhost/index -> page not found.  and localhost/index/about server interprets as about controller which is totally not i meant..

Comment: Which web server are you using? If Apache, do you have your .htaccess correctly configured?

Comment: zend server for ubuntu. apache2

Comment: See my edit.. you need to have an .htaccess file in your public directory (assuming standard ZF structure) that looks like this

Comment: @manyxcxi is the IndexController limited for actions in Zend? I've never really thought about it, but you can't really add actions to it (I guess?)

Comment: You can add any actions to a controller you want, they're (for all intents and purposes) not limited. You simply need to create the action in the controller that you want. If you want the URL to be `localhost/about` you need to create an `AboutController` with an `indexAction`. If you want the URL to be `localhost/index/about` you just need to create an `aboutAction` in the `IndexController`.

Comment: The concept gets easier, I promise. Also, the above is a very basic explanation, because you can do all kinds of hard/fancy things with URL rewriting, custom routes, etc. I've built some VERY complex apps with just the basic controller/action URL and it hasn't been an issue.

Comment: hey manyxcxi i have the same .htaccesss file. i also tried yours(which is adding the first line) but it didnt solve my problem.

Comment: What happens if you comment out the `init` function in `IndexController`?

Comment: index.php should be in your public folder- assuming a standard ZF project layout.

Comment: i think i did something wrong with the config for apache. since it points to the public folder which only containts the rountering index.php(which is the only page cant be found, because localhost/index -> page not found).

Comment: i found the bug i have to add "AllowOverride all"

Answer (score 0):

I think it's exactly the error message is saying, which is that you need a controller for `about` that you don't have. In the url `http://localhost/index.php/about`, `about` would be a completely separate controller that you'd need to establish.

Comment: but i expect the server interprets index as controller about as action.

Comment: @Nissan911 and I see why you would think that. However, Zend is looking for an `about` controller in the above format.